# Binaural Recordings

Tags: binaural, field-recording, setup

Anyone who is doing binaural recordings, what mics/setup are you using (makes & models of mics and for setup: binaural head, in-ear etc.) I'm looking at investing in some and would like to have some advice. I know [this question has been asked already](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/2147/binaural-recording-and-asset-creation) but I wanted to re-launch the question to see if we can get some more response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I was on an extremely tight budget (as usual) and I bought [these](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/BINAURAL-EAR-MOUNTED-ELECTRET-CONDENSER-MICROPHONE-/270504397416?pt=UK_Music_Instruments_Microphones_MJ&hash=item3efb518a68). For the exra power needed for the electret mics I bought [this](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/STEREO-MICROPHONE-BATTERY-PHANTOM-POWER-PREAMP-MODULE-/270620193225?pt=UK_Consumer_Professional_RL&hash=item3f023871c9) and [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/3-5mm-Stereo-Socket-6-35mm-Adapter/dp/B003OSUY8I/ref=sr_1_37?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1296230391&sr=1-37) to connect it to the inputs on my Zoom H4 recorder.

With this cheap and cheerful set up I made recordings such as this one [MARKET](http://soundcloud.com/chris-whitehead/whitby-uk-market-stall-being-dismantled-12-12-10) and this one [XMAS DECORATIONS](http://soundcloud.com/chris-whitehead/musical-xmas-decorations-at-victoria-garden-centre-whitby). The only adjustment to the originals was a bit of Eq to bring out the bass.

Chris W

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.neumann.com/?lang=en&id=current_microphones&cid=ku100_description) would be the top end. But I've seen binaural heads built out of mannequin heads as well.

A lot of folks swear by [Sound Professionals](http://www.soundprofessionals.com/cgi-bin/gold/category/110/mics) binaural setups, which are way more entry level. I've heard some good recordings made by the headphone model.

I would also look into making your own set with a couple of matched lavs. [DPA](http://www.dpamicrophones.com/en/products.aspx?c=item&category=128&item=24035) 4060s or 4061s sound great and would serve you well.

Comment: @Justin - Yeah I'd love to get a Neuman Dummy Head. I've seen Gordon 'The Soundtracker' Hempton using this in some videos. Sadly, I'm not rich!

+1 on the DPA idea. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Yes, the DPAs would be a great choice and could also be used for other things. I absolutely love my 4060s, they sound more like a medium sized condenser than lavs. I've make some nice stealth recordings with those mounted on a hardshell backpack. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have  a pair of 4060 on a kit by [Core-Sound](http://www.core-sound.com/bk/1.php),

They sound very rich and good in the low end. Very low profile too!

I have another [kit](http://www.core-sound.com/mics/1.php) of binaurals by Core-sound, They are less sensitive with less bass and high's.  The high end binaurals with the DPA 4060 are really better.

Answer (score 1):

For those of use who can't afford a dummy head, we can use our own dumb head with the help of these little guys: http://www.sonicstudios.com/dsm.htm with very decent results.

I got that tip from Karen at http://whitenoisemp3s.com/ and she's got some very lovely recordings available using them.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a pair of omnis I would invest in a Jecklin disc.

http://www.josephson.com/tn5.html